# Automatically getting percentage based on two input fields in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to Java.can anyone tell how to calculate percentage of two input numbers.Will I have to write some javascript? Can anyone suggest?

Here is my code

```
<td class="bg1" style="width:22%;"><input type="text" style="width:40px;" name="score2"  align="center" maxlength="4" onblur="validateField('DIGIT1',this)" />/<input type="text" style="width:40px;" name="totmarks2"  align="center" maxlength="4" onblur="validateField('DIGIT1',this)"/></td>
<td class="bg2" width="15%;"><input type="text"  name="percentage2"  maxlength="5" /></td>
```

Comment: Maybe you're looking for Javascript. [Java is not Javascript](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_javascript.xml).

Comment: What does this have to do with Java? This is HTML with a little bit of CSS and Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

`Java` and `javascript` are not the same. And yes, you need to write `javascript` for this, e.g.:

```
var score = document.getElementsByName("score2")[0].value;
var totalMarks = document.getElementsByName("totmarks2")[0].value;

var percentage = (score/totalMarks)*100;

document.getElementsByName("percentage2")[0].value = percentage;
```